# SFTP Server not allowing a Logic App- with routed traffic to one IP- to connect

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, sftp, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

So I've routed traffic from my Logic App (Standard) to one IP using this [method](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/static-ip-of-logic-app-standard-using-nat-gateway/ba-p/3721443)(Through VNet and NAT Gateway setup)

Although when I've whitelisted that IP to an SFTP server (I've set one up with blob storage) and run the workflow, I get a BadGateway error. I even whitelisted or added the VNet that my Logic App was using to see if that would help- but no luck. When I allow all IP's to connect- the workflow succeeds.

[image]

Is there something I'm overlooking? Any way to get this to succeed with one IP?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this several times, I do not think there is a way of doing this with the native SFTP connector in Logic Apps (if I am wrong about this I would love to be shown so). As I understand it the native SFTP connector has its traffic outbound from the pooled IPs of the service even if you vNet-integrate your Logic App, the connector is not running in your Logic App, in other words.

Docs:

1. SFTP-SSH is a managed connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sftpwithssh/
2. Managed connectors are outbound from these IPs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses#azure-logic-apps

Comment: Thanks for the info. Did you accomplish this any other way?

Comment: I keep thinking about using an SMTP client in Python or some other language and running that in an Azure Function, that would be a good way, assuming the traffic from that Azure Function would then be forced outbound through the vNet and out via a NAT Gateway. A less than great way that I did have working in the past was PowerShell on a VM using Azure Automation and a Hybrid Worker. But this less-than-great way would be cheaper in terms of Azure resources if you need the Azure resources only for this purpose.